# font size much bigger in gh pages than local host

Tags: create-react-app, github-pages

My repository is located at https://leviyorbach2.github.io/contac_8/
The app works on localhost - in gh pages the font is large and the app doesn't work - I am on a mac running on chrome - have looked at previous answers to this and they don't seem relevant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the difference between expected and actual behaviour. If it is just the font size: That might have something to do with browser defaults and adding a `font-size` in css might help. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzpVC.png) is what the page looks like on my end.

Comment: the app in localhost works properly - gh pages does not work you can only see two contacts and it doesnt scroll down

Comment: i just tried it in safari and the font size is different but the app works

Comment: i just tried it again after changing font -size and the problem is resolved thanks for the help